# Bind label from computation - oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-apex-19.2

I try bind label text from computation but I don't know how render html.

When put in label static html work fine.

Eg.

[image]

Any solution how fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to control output escaping in substitution strings. In the label value, use `&P71_COMPUTATION!RAW.` instead. This is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/htmdb/using-substitution-strings.html#GUID-CA3ABA44-D03D-4396-A527-B160F1FFE933). This is the 21.1 doc but this feature has been around for a while.

Comment: Don't have this option!

Comment: Sorry I just updated my answer after a test

Comment: Nice, tnx, if xou have any link documentation please put in answer.